# How to check empty tables using SQL Select or Execute?

Tags: sql, databases, return-value

```
If[SQLExecute[con, "Select * from TABLE"] == "{}", Print["TRUE"], Print["FALSE"]]
```

I need to know the way, if the TABLE is empty or not

Comment: Why `=="{}"`? It's not going to return a string to you...  It should be `== {}`. But retrieving all columns from all rows in the entire table (which could potentially be huge) is not a very good idea just to see if the table is empty, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` instead.

Comment: Depending on your situation it may be better to run this in one pass and filter that list for further processing. E.g. in postgresql `select schemaname, relname, n_live_tup from pg_stat_user_tables order by relname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one options:

```
If[SQLExecute[con, "Select * from TABLE","MaxRows" -> 1] == {},True, False]
```

If it's just a test, Using `MaxRows` you can prevent an unnecessary data load.